# "I would have done X if Y would Z" or "I would have done X if Y would have Z"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

What's the correct construction?

Example sentence:

> "I ate the goldfish," I would have confessed if those words **wouldn't sound** crazy.
>
> "I ate the goldfish," I would have confessed if those words wouldn't **have sounded** crazy.

Which is the correct alternative and why?

Note: I checked Google and I think there's a third option: *I would have confessed if those words **didn't sound** crazy.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would confess if those words wouldn't sound crazy.
>
> I would confess if those words didn't sound crazy.
>
> I would have confessed if those words wouldn't have sounded crazy.
>
> I would have confessed if those words didn't sound crazy.
>
> I would have confessed if those words had not sounded crazy.

These are all idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct with the third option.
It should be : 
I would have confessed if those words didn't sound crazy.